# Finding a single speed kit for an old campagnolo from 1997 with screw on freehub

Tags: freewheel, single-speed, campagnolo

I have an old Campagnolo from 1997 that I want to turn into an single speed.

My problem is finding a kit that will fit the freehub. The outer diameter of this freehub including teeth is 34 mm, but when I find a kit like this one http://www.ebay.com/itm/400876993505 the dimensions are off. The cog I bought from ebay has a smaller diameter that the freehub.

What should I be looking for when it's an old 1997 screw-on freehub? Would it be easier just to replace the freehub, and if yes, which one should I pick to make sure it's going to fit?

Measuring the freehub
[image: measuring freewheel]

Comment: If you are going to end up replacing the free hub, it's probably easier to just replace back wheel with a proper single-speed/fixed hub and then you don't have to worry about using a conversion kit.

Comment: What do you mean by screw on? This looks like a regular 1997 freehub to me, freewheels are older stuff. Campagnolo freehubs have different splines than everything else, good luck trying to find singlespeed conversion kit for one.

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't look like a screw on freewheel hub, that's an 8 speed freehub designed for a slide on cassette. I have the same one. Its the older design called Exa drive. When Campagnolo went to 9 speed the shape of the spines were changed and made deeper. This is why your conversions kit doesnt work , as its designed for the newer style freehubs. See the page below

http://branfordbike.com/articles/cassettes-and-cogs-pg60.htm

Unfortunately you cannot just swap the freehub body for a newer 9/10/11 speed one as the axles are different sizes. You either need to buy a newer style campagnolo hub, or you can take a cog from a Campagnolo 8 speed cassette and use spacers either side. You may find the chain jumps of the cassette cog though as the teeth are not as deep as a dedicated single speed cog.

If you're buyng a new hub/wheel for single speed you may even want to buy a Shimano one as they are cheaper and single speed cogs are more widely available in a range of sizes.